# Customize a Shared Schedule in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

**Does anyone know of a way to create more complex shared schedules? If not, do you know of a way to simplify the schedule needs I have detailed below?**

Creating a shared schedule in sql server 2008's SSRS does not seem to offer any additional complexities compared to report-specific schedules.

What I really need is the ability to create a schedule tied to my company's fiscal calendar. For example, it would be great to have a schedule that would send a report at the close of every fiscal month. Another example is of a report that emails throughout the day to provide operational updates. The report sends in intervals that do not align to anything I can express in the below configuration screen but rather to business needs. On Monday for example, the report will send at 8:15 AM, 12:15 PM, 2:15 PM, 4:15 PM, 6:15 PM and 9:15 PM. I cannot determine how to accomplish this pattern in one schedule, so I use multiple. Since the pattern is different for different days of the week, many schedules are needed. This is inefficient and cumbersome to manage when adding or removing recipients.

When first learning of shared schedules that could be configured on the server, I thought these problems would be solved. I am disappointed with the options below. The "Script" menu item remains gray through the process, so modifying the code this would generate does not appear to be an option either.

Thanks!

[image: New Shared Schedule]

Comment: You can get more flexibility by manually editing the schedule that gets created against the SQL Agent.  However it won't allow anything as complex as you require.  I suspect the only real option is to write a custom app which calls the report web service on its own schedule and delivers them itself.

Comment: Thanks, Sir Crispalot. It's seems like it would be so easy only if multiple schedules like above could be created an tied to a parent schedule. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sir Crispalot notes in comments, you can't modify the SSRS schedule to this degree. A Shared Schedule doesn't give any options beyond the single schedule per report.

But you can change the schedule of the SQL agent that executes the subscription. Here you can associate multiple schedules with a subscription.

Another approach is to dynamically change the subscriptions and their schedules with some other code, such as a .NET .exe running on a schedule, or called by a SQL Agent. You could build a pretty nice scheduling interface for all your reports, storing the schedules however you like, then dynamically changing the subscriptions themselves: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/DynamicSSRSSubscriptions.aspx